# Make a div area transparent, other than the area where images is?

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

I have a Div with 2-3 icons in it. The icons are horizontally aligned on top of a big image div.

I want bottom image to be visible in padding area between icons. Which property can help me to achieve this functionality ? Any pointers ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style your `div` with something like this:

```
background: transparent, ...your other images...;
```

That assumes your icons are shown as `background-images`, if not, just specify `background: transparent;` to your `div`.